# Why do we belive that P = BPP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

My teacher said that this is what most of the reaserchers belives and it seems wierd to me.

I know that after amplification the vast majority of random r's will be sufficiont for all x i.e.
for all $|x| = n - M(x,r)$ will be right. But why do we belive that we can find this $r$ efficiently?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity)